# 960gs Opera & Internet Explorer Rendering Issue

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, internet-explorer-8, opera, 960.gs

So I was testing out the 960gs when I encountered a problem with the Opera & IE8 browser.
Below is an image with the page rendered in Opera (But same error happens in IE8.)
[image]

I don't care about the buttons not being styled correctly, but it's the divs aligning horizontally that bugs me.

Below is the same page rendered with chrome (looks the same in firefox).
[image]

Anyone knows what the problem might be?

Comment: Below is the source code to the page with one HTML and three CSS files.
http://cl.ly/Br4g

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML has incorrect tags. buttons cannot have hrefs. Only links (a tags) can.

Your CSS does not have gradients for Opera, IE only for Safari/Chrome.You would do that using -o-linear-gradient(top, #ade2ff, #0588fa);

Answer (score 0):

Well, **either** you use `<button>` **or** `<a>`. If you start your buttons with `<button>` you can't end them with `<a>`. Just choose one of them and your grid layout works.